# Exposure date is returned as null even though the Exif information is available

Tags: c#, .net, metadata-extractor

I am processing about 10,000 images and am using [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) to extract the Exif data. It works for about 7,000 of the images but fails for the remainder.

This is the relevant code,

```
public static string ExposureDateTime(string fileName, string logFile)
{
    string dateTime = null;
    try
    {
        var metadatadir = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(fileName);
        var subIfdDirectory = metadatadir.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
        dateTime = subIfdDirectory?.GetDescription(ExifDirectoryBase.TagDateTimeOriginal);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFile, true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.Message, fileName);
        }
    }
    return dateTime;
}
```

Applying a breakpoint to the `dateTime` string, the value is returned as `null` for the files that fail.

However, if I open the image uisng the native Photos application in Windows, I can see the exposure date correctly under File Information.

For a file that fails, this is the Exif [directory](https://pastebin.com/RhxpJLAz) and [tags](https://pastebin.com/8Bjcb8nH). 
For a file that succeeds, this is the Exif [directory](https://pastebin.com/yeSLXvSK) and [tags](https://pastebin.com/ucSPgS5Z). 
I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: It's consistent? Same file always pass and same always fail?

Comment: Yes, exactly consistent. I will add a pastebin for a Exif directory that is successful.

Comment: Have you reversed your working/failing tags links? It seems that DateTimeOriginal simply isn't in the images that return you null.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I ended up using `FileDirectory?.GetDescription(FileMetadataDirectory.TagFileModifiedDate` instead.